# Keyboard shortcuts to add images on the new new Twitter site

Tags: twitter, keyboard-shortcuts

The [new new Twitter site](http://fly.twitter.com/) is awesome.

I'm not sure if they were there before but you can now access a list of keyboard short cuts by simply pressing <kbd>?</kbd>

[image: Twitter - Keyboard shortcuts]

When I press <kbd>N</kbd> it brings up the new Tweet box, is there another keyboard short cut that will allow me to bring up the Open File Dialog so that I don't have to click the `Add an Image` button?

[image: Add an Image - Keyboard Shortcut ??]

Comment: How do you activate it already? (The new site I mean.)

Comment: @Alex: I think it's the same roll out process and previous versions - you just have to wait for it to appear! :)

Comment: I thought there might be a trick to force it. :) Thanks!

Comment: @Alex: According to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/MobileSupport/statuses/144919695554920451) if you download and log in using the new Twitter app for iPhone or Android then the new Web design will magically happen for you soon after.

Comment: I don't own any of those, so patience is the best option :))

Comment: @Barry That doesn't work for me..

Comment: @sathya Woah there cowboy, it's not immediate. Happened for me about 24-36hours after I had logged in using the new Android App :)

Comment: @Barry but, but I've been using the new iOS for ~24 hours now :( (yeah, yeah I know, patience :P )

Comment: Just to join in here, I got new twitter before updating the android app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible.

For security, I don't think this would be a good idea, to even implement as an extension. Users with malicious intent can use this to their advantage to gain access to files on the a next computer.

Comment: You are right this is probably down to security, although it would still be nice to be able to tab to it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking once the new tweet box is opened or something that will just open the "open file" dialog without entering any text?

Once the new tweet box has opened (having used the <kbd>N</kbd> shortcut), then the cursor immediately goes to the text box. Even using one of the other shortcuts (say, <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> for going to favourites) just gets entered into the box. So I doubt there is a shortcut for the photos once you've popped open the new tweet box.

Currently it doesn't look like they have any other shortcuts that do this. Even <kbd>N</kbd> then tabbing goes all round the site, but never seems to hit the photo button.